# Opening an Excel 2003 workbook in Excel 2010 32-bit causes bogus circular reference and crashes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2003

We have a workbook that we have been using daily for many years in Excel 2003.

We are now migrating to Excel 2010, and have encountered the following problem.

When the workbook is opened in 2010 (32-bit version on 64-bit Windows 7) (clean open, no other workbooks present) and we try calculating any of the worksheets (even the simplest one), we get the following error:

"Microsoft Excel cannot calculate a formula.  There is a circular reference in an open workbook, but the references that cause it cannot be listed for you. Try editing the last formula you entered or removing it with the Undo command."

This does not seem to happen in the 64-bit version of 2010.

If we open the workbook in Excel 2003, there are no calculation issues.  If we open the workbook in 2003 and calculate one sheet (shift-F9), or even calculate one cell that is a trivial reference to another cell (=E4), and then save the workbook, we do not get quite the same behaviour: when opened in 2010, we can calculate various sheets (shift-F9 or worksheet.calculate), but when running a macro to calculate all sheets in the workbook, it crashes at some point on one of the sheets.  Again, this does not happen in the 64-bit version of 2010.

Has anyone else encountered this problem with Excel 2003-workbooks in Excel 2010, 32-bit version?  I cannot find any references to a problem of this description anywhere.  Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that you have some event macros triggering circular errors? http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/518652-circular-reference-in-an-open-workbook.html

Comment: No, I wish it were that simple. And that wouldn't be consistent with the observation that calculating one cell in 2003, then saving and opening in 2010 removes many of the problems, nor consistent with the fact that there are no problems in 64-bit version. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just FYI this question probably is a better fit for SuperUser.com, it does not seem to be at all programming-related, or, if it is, you have not provided nearly enough information to go on. I'm going to suggest that the moderators migrate it to that environment, where perhaps you will get a better answer.

Comment: Ah. No, its not really programming related, it seems to be a bug in Excel 2010. I will investigate SuperUser.com.  Perhaps I should review the target purpose of StackOverflow and its related sites? Thanks.

Comment: OK, I have (created account and...) posted it in SuperUser.com. I would prefer to leave this here for a few days before deleting. My experience is that the StackOverflow community is second to none in the quality of members, and I expect I may get a more knowledgeable response here in any case. This will be a good test. If I get a solution on superUser.com, I will delete this entire question. (And if you're a responder who's read this comment, don't go to my equivalent question on superUser.com and post your response there and foil my experiment! lol.) Thanks.